# How to control who can login the host via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a host that is using NIS for user authentication. Both user A and B are valid user. But how to only allow user A login the host via ssh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH is configured via the file [/etc/ssh/sshd_config](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sshd_config+5).

See the above documentation as regarding the parameters `AllowGroups, AllowUsers, DenyGroups, DenyUsers`.